# Data is not being stored on MSSQL from Android Studio

Tags: sql-server, android-studio, mssql-jdbc

I think my APP that I made in Android Studio is connected to the server of my database because when I check it using a TextView it says its connected. The problem is when I press the register button, no data is being transferred to the database. The Table on my database is still empty.
I don't know what code to paste here so I'll just paste my Register.java file.
DISCLAIMER: I'm still a student learning about SQL, I just watched 2 videos on youtube on how to connect AndroidStudio and MSSQL but the same thing happened, no data is being stored on the database.

```
package com.example.login;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String ip = "192.168.1.5";
    private  static String port = "1433";
    private static String Classes = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String db = "DB_SWEENEY_USERS";
    private static String un = "depota";
    private static String pass = "1234";
    Connection con;
    Statement stmt;
    private TextView txtView1;
    private EditText InputFirstName;
    private EditText InputLastName;
    private EditText InputPassword;
    private EditText InputEmail;
    private static final String TAG = "Register";
    private TextView txtViewPickDate;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
    public static final String PERSON_NAME = "com.name.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register2);
        RadioGroup rdGroup = findViewById(R.id.rdGroup);
        rdGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            String gender;
                switch (i){
                    case R.id.maleBtn:
                        gender = "Male";
                        break;
                    case R.id.femaleBtn:
                        gender = "Female";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }); //CHOOSE MALE AND FEMALE

        txtViewPickDate = findViewById(R.id.txtViewPickDate);
        txtViewPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Register.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener,year,month,day);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });//DATE PICKER
        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month +1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet:mm/dd/yyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                txtViewPickDate.setText(date);
            }
        };//DISPLAY DATE PICKER

        InputFirstName = findViewById(R.id.InputFirstName);
        InputLastName = findViewById(R.id.InputLastName);
        InputPassword = findViewById(R.id.InputPassword);
        InputEmail = findViewById(R.id.InputEmail);
        EditText InputConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.InputConfirmPassword);
        txtView1 = findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
        Button regBtn = findViewById(R.id.regBtn);




        regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new Register.registerUser().execute("");


                /* String password = InputPassword.getText().toString();
                String confirm = InputConfirmPassword.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password) || TextUtils.isEmpty(confirm)) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password field is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(password.equals(confirm)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Main_Menu.class);
                    String personName = InputFirstName.getText().toString() + " " + InputLastName.getText().toString();
                    intent.putExtra(PERSON_NAME, personName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Password don't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }*/
            }
        });

    }


    public class registerUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        String z = "";
        Boolean isSuccess= false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            txtView1.setText("Sending Data to Datbase");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            txtView1.setText("Registration Successful");
            InputFirstName.setText("");
            InputLastName.setText("");
            InputPassword.setText("");
            InputEmail.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                 con = connectionClass(un.toString(), pass.toString(),db.toString(),ip.toString());
                 if (con==null){
                     z = "ERROR DEPOTA NA ANO NI MAN";
                 }else{
                     String sql = "INSERT INTO register (firstName,lastName,middleInitial,gender,bDate,uName,email,pass) VALUES ('"+InputFirstName.getText()+"','"+InputLastName.getText()+"','"+"NULL"+"','"+"NULL"+"','"+"NULL"+"','"+"NULL"+"','"+InputEmail.getText()+"','"+InputPassword.getText()+"')";
                     stmt = con.createStatement();
                     stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                 }
            }catch (Exception e){
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = e.getMessage();
            }
            return z;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionClass(String user, String password, String database, String server){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String connectionURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" +server+"/" +database+";user=" + user+";password=" +password + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SQL Connection Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect and store data on my database on MSSQL from the app I made on Android Studio. I think the MSSQL server is connected to the Android Studio but the problem is no data is being stored on the table in the database on MSSQL.

Comment: Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough! – Please read http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You should not use an android app to directly hit a database, you should hit an API service, SOAP service or similar that hits the database.

Comment: I'm just going to pass this as a school project. Thanks for the advice tho.
So I should use an API service then? Is it easier if I do that?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say it's easier to use an API but it's a best practice and not difficult (you could use docker). I'm certain your mobile banking app  certainly doesn't connect directly to a database server :-)

Comment: If its for school project you could except it but if you want to learn....